# xamarin forms list view action menu

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there any way to make a design using xamarin forms ? 
I want to open a menu as on images when I press three dot.

**EDIT :**

[xamarin-list-view](https://ibb.co/cL5DPz)

Comment: what about using popup plugin https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup ?

Comment: i am looking for some thing like on image

Answer (score 0):

> I want to open a menu as on images when I press three dot.

This is a known issue when you set `icon` for `ToolbarItem` with order `Secondary`.

When I look in to the `NavigationPageRenderer` source code I found that this --> [NavigationPageRenderer](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/AppCompat/NavigationPageRenderer.cs#L854) :

```
foreach (ToolbarItem item in _toolbarTracker.ToolbarItems)
{
    IMenuItemController controller = item;
    item.PropertyChanged += OnToolbarItemPropertyChanged;
    if (item.Order == ToolbarItemOrder.Secondary)
    {
        IMenuItem menuItem = menu.Add(item.Text);
        menuItem.SetEnabled(controller.IsEnabled);
        menuItem.SetOnMenuItemClickListener(new GenericMenuClickListener(controller.Activate));
    }
    else
    {
         IMenuItem menuItem = menu.Add(item.Text);
         UpdateMenuItemIcon(context, menuItem, item);
         menuItem.SetEnabled(controller.IsEnabled);
         menuItem.SetShowAsAction(ShowAsAction.Always);
         menuItem.SetOnMenuItemClickListener(new GenericMenuClickListener(controller.Activate));
    }
}
```

It means when we use the secondary toolbar item in `Xamarin.Form`, no icon will be showed. It is a by-design issue.

Bug: [Xamarin.Forms Secondary ToolbarItem Icon not showing](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3550)

GitHub PR fix: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/1873

### Suggestion

If you must implement this feature in your project, you need rewrite the `NavigationPageRenderer`, and it will very complex.